# Jest interceptor angular with toHaveBeenCalledTimes

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have a problem in my tests which are always OK even when they have to be knocked out.
I created an interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private store: Store<RoutingCustom>) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        () => {},
        (err: object) => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 501) {
            this.store.dispatch(
              RoutingCustom.login()
            );
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I did tests to validate my interceptor

```
describe('ErrorHttpInterceptor', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let store: MockStore<RoutingInterface.RouterState>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: ErrorHttpInterceptor,
          multi: true
        },
        provideMockStore()
      ]
    });
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  test('error 501', () => {
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.stub();
    httpClient.get('/test').subscribe(
      data => {},
      error => {
        expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
      }
    );

    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`/test`);
    req.flush('Error', { status: 501, statusText: 'Error' });
  });
});
```

However the toHaveBeenCalledTimes method I can put 0 or 15 I still have the test which passes to OK.
Anyone have an idea for testing the interceptor?

Thank you

Comment: The test is currently synchronous, it ignores all asynchronous assertions that happen inside it. You could switch to promises and `async` function and do `await expect(httpClient.get('/test').toPromise()).rejects.toThrow()`, etc. Or set up Angular test helpers and use `fakeAsync`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I can't do this to test that there is indeed my dispacher who is called :(

Comment: I found, to test this, just put the tests on the dispacher after the flush and not in the subscribe and it's ok :)